# About exactness of $Hom$ functor?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, projective-module, free-modules, flatness

We know that a module $P$ is projective if and only if the functor $Hom(P,-):R-Mod \to Ab$ is exact, i.e it preserves epimorphisms: If $\alpha: M \to N$ is an epimorphism of modules then $Hom(P,\alpha):Hom(P,M)\to Hom(P,N)$ is an epimorphism of abelian groups. Now I'm trying to find some thing similar for a non-projective module $P$ but with finite projective dimension, say $pd(P)\leq d$. I know that in this case $Hom(P,-)$ is not exact, is there any condition for an epimorphism $\alpha: M \to N$ to have $Hom(P,\alpha):Hom(P,M)\to Hom(P,N)$ is an epimorphism of abelian groups?

Comment: An obviously sufficient, but fairly restrictive, condition is that $\alpha$ be split. Furthermore, by general abstract nonsense, $\mathrm{Hom}(P,\alpha)$ is an epimorphism if and only if $\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\ker(\alpha))\rightarrow\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,M)$ is injective, but this map is not easy to pin down unless $\alpha$ is something more concrete. At the very least, vanishing of $\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\ker(\alpha))$ is sufficient and perhaps you know this group in some contexts.